# loading from xib and translatesautoresizingmaskintoconstraints

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var vsuper: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let  v = view2.getView()

    vsuper.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    vsuper.addSubview(v)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

//xib file

```
import UIKit

class view2: UIView {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}
static func getView()->view2{
    let v = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("view2", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as! consentview
   // v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v;
}
```

}

While I load xib into another view in story board it doesn't get added inside that view if translateautoresizingmaskintoconstraints is set to false but if I remove that line it gets added to the view.

if I set it to false it takes space on top left otherwise it gets added inside the view. Why so ? even though I am adding it tov super

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not set the constraints. `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` means you don't want the xib frame to be translated into constraints thus you will setup constraints yourself. Thats why its not assigning any bounds to the xib view on your superview. Try making some constraints with the superview after addSubview() call. such as,

```
v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vsuper.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vsuper.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vsuper.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vsuper.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
vsuper.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: But I want to know even if I am not giving it any constraints at least I am telling to to get added tov super. But it doesn't get added inside that view, instead it appears on top left

Comment: See, if any view doesn't get its bounds calculated and added to the window, its default frame is (0,0,0,0) which means it's x and y co-ordinates are (0,0). So auto-layout engine automatically starts placing it starting from point (0,0) which is the top left according to the cartesian plain system. Thats why its showing over there instead of the vsuper range.
if the answer is correct for you, please approve the answer and give an up-vote. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 import UIKit

 class MyView: UIView {

    // your outlets from your view can be there

    // your functions for your view
    func myFunc() {

    }
 }


import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var myView: MyView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      if let contentView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? MyView {

        myView = contentView
        self.view.addSubview(myView)

      }

      // set background color your custom view
      myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

      // call functions for your custom view
      myView.myFunc()

   }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the reason why if I am adding a view in my code .. it is not added to superview and take top left space ?